# Display all categories as plain text

Tags: loop, categories

Within my loop i'm currently outputting one category that a post is assigned to as plain text. Its being used as a class name within my markup (not visible to users) but if a post is assigned multiple categories, my code below only outputs one category, how do I get ALL categories (that the post has assigned to it) to appear as class names instead?

```
<?php //begin new query
                $project_query = new WP_Query('cat=14,15,16,17,18,19');?>

                <?php while ($project_query->have_posts()) : $project_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>

                    <!-- I NEED CATEGORY NAMES TO APEEAR AS CLASS NAME ON THIS LINE BELOW -->                   
                    <div class="element <?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->category_nicename; ?> sports">
                        <div class="element_inner">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">

                                <img src="<?php the_field('leading_image') ?>" />
                                <div class="meta"><?php the_title(); ?></div>

                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="four-col-shadow"></div>
                    </div>

                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general solution for all taxonomies. To be used inside the loop (else replace `get_the_ID()` with post ID ):

```
$taxonomy = 'category';
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy );
if( $terms ){
   $term_slugs = array_map('esc_attr',wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug'));
   $class = implode(' ', $term_slugs);
}else{
   $class = 'no-term';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So in terms of my code, how do I integrate your answer into my existing code? What variable do I echo to output the category names?

Comment: The variable `$class` should contain a space delimited list of category slugs. So you should use it as follows: `<div class="element <?php echo $class; ?> sports">`